# How to Solve error in Package com.actsoft

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, netbeans-7, java

I am new on java i wanted to import the existing project on Netbeans 7.0.1 ,jdk 7.0,and glassfish.I imported the project in the netbeans with some external packages but i am not able to solve two problem in package connectionManager.java & log.java .when i Open the file ConnectionManager.java

DBPool pool = DBPool.getPool(dbAlias);

Error:method getPool in class com.caucho.sql.DBPool cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String

### reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

similarly when i open the log.java

PropertyConfigurator.resetConfiguration();

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method resetConfiguration()

### location: class org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to learn some basics....maybe [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) or [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) can help.

Anyway...your first problem seems to be the parameter `dbAlias`

Try this instead: `DBPool pool = DBPool.getPool();`

The second problem says the class `org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator` doesn't have the method `resetConfiguration()`. A quick search on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.java/) reveals that this seems to be true. I don't know why this method call is there...but there is probably something wrong with either the call or the imported libs....

Comment: Hi!! I just going through your link .it's good for basic.but still i am getting same problem... yeah, i am also thinking there is problem in parameter but it is defined in the code .so i can't remove dbALias...In the second problem I search the required jar file and added to my project but i am not getting solution of resetConfiguration.So can i edit on package ??

Comment: If it is your package you can...but it is probably not your package :)